# Maximize area of isosceles triangle with given median

Tags: optimization, maxima-minima, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

Given icoscales triangle with sides $a, b, c, a = b$; median performed to the side of triangle, say, to b, denoted as $m_b.$
**Note:** I need to maximize area of triangle. I need to solve it **using inequalities**, not Lagrange multipliers etc.

Firstly i tried to solve it using median formula $m_b^2 = \dfrac{2a^2 + 2c^2 - b^2}{4} = \dfrac{a^2}{4} + \dfrac{c^2}{2}$ and Geron's formula of sqare of triangle:
\begin{align}
S^2 &= p(p - a)(p-b)(p -c), \; p = \dfrac{2a+c}{2}  = a + \dfrac{c}{2}, \\
S^2 &= \Big(a^2 - \dfrac{c^2}{4} \Big)  \dfrac{c^2}{4} = \Big(\dfrac{a^2}{4}  - \dfrac{c^2}{16}\Big)c^2 
= \Big(m^2_b - \dfrac{9c^2}{16}\Big) c^2 = \\ 
&=\Bigg(\sqrt{\Big(m^2_b - \dfrac{9c^2}{16}\Big) c^2 }\Bigg)^2 \overset{AM-GM}{\leq} 
\Big(\dfrac{m^2_b}{2}+ \dfrac{7c^2}{32}\Big)^2 
\end{align}
Then since inequality turns to equality iff $m^2_b - \dfrac{9c^2}{16} = c^2$, i got  $c = \dfrac{4}{5}m_b$
and $S_{\max} = \dfrac{16}{25}m^2_b$.
Well, it seems wrong answer.

How can i solve it right-way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try completing the square:

\begin{align}
S^2 &= \left(m^2_b - \dfrac{9c^2}{16}\right)c^2= m^2_b c^2 - \dfrac{9c^4}{16}  \\ &=  \left(\dfrac23m^2_b\right)^2  - \left(\dfrac23m^2_b\right)^2 + 2\left(\dfrac23m^2_b\right) \left(\dfrac34c^2\right) - \left(\dfrac34c^2\right)^2 \\ &=  \dfrac49m^4_b  - \left( \dfrac23m^2_b-\dfrac34c^2\right)^2 \\ &\le  \dfrac49m^4_b 
\end{align}

with equality (i.e. a maximum) when $\frac23m^2_b=\frac34c^2$, i.e. $c= \sqrt{\frac89}m_b$, giving $S_{\max}=\frac23m^2_b$.

Comment: Yes, your sol looks great, but i'm trying to understand, why is my way was leading to the wrong answer, i.e. why can't i **not constructing** the complete square.

Comment: @Juicer I would have thought the arithmetic-geometric inequality might be applied to $\sqrt{\left(\dfrac43m^2_b -\dfrac34 c^2 \right)\left(\dfrac34 c^2 \right)} \le \dfrac23m^2_b$ since you want to eliminate $c$.  Your method failed to eliminate $c$